# What is the statue in the music video for "Sick Boy"?

Tags: identification

[image]Recently I viewed the [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eACohWVwTOc) for the song "Sick Boy" by the Chainsmokers. Does anyone know who is the statue featured in the video of? I just can't find any information on this although I assume it's an ancient Roman or Greek figure.

Comment: A better image would really help...

Comment: @LarsBosteen That image is about as good as it gets, it's only in the video for a couple of seconds (1:38-1:40) and the clean shot is on screen for even less than that. It doesn't seem to have any obvious context from the video either.

Comment: You know, not all statues depict someone historically important.

Comment: Sure, but then it is uncommon for random statues to be featured as well

Comment: There is a significant difference between "being featured" and "being a part of the *atrezzo*." Being in the background, unfocused, and shown only for a couple of seconds would point to the later possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot of image to go on, but by the [song lyrics](https://www.reddit.com/r/thelastpsychiatrist/comments/7rqy72/the_chainsmokers_new_song_is_about_narcissism_can/) I would guess the main statue shown should be representing [Narcissus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology)).

> And don't believe the **narcissism**
>
> When everyone projects
>
> And expects you to listen to 'em

and

> Welcome to the **narcissism**
>
> We're united under our indifference
>
> I am the, I am the, I am the sick boy